# log4net - no log file produced

Tags: log4net

I have this as my config file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    </configSections>

    <log4net>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="c:\\logging\\EwsSearch.log" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
            <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>

    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I then have in my C# code:

```cs
public class VsiEWSSearch
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(VsiEWSSearch));

    public EWSResponse PdeProcessInquiry(int BusinessLineCode, int ClientCaseId, string callingApp)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("VSI.EWSSearch.config"));

        logger.Error("This is an error");
```

No log file is produced even though I have adjusted permissions for the directory. What's wrong?

Comment: I am running under a framework that runs WCF services. It is logging to its logging directory file. It still seems like config file is being ignored

Answer (score 1):

The `root` node has to be inside the `log4net` node. Depending on the type of configuration file you need to make some further adjustments:

- If you have a standalone config file for log4net then you need to remove the `configuration` and `configSections` node. I also think that log4net is not going to find you configuration file unless you specify the full path (you can of course do that without hard-coding any path in your application).
- If you are simply using app.config then you do not need further modifications, but you need to call the `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` method without any argument.

Note: You should call the `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` method only once in your application.

Comment: I changed some code according to the local expert: private static ILog logger = null; public EWSResponse PdeProcessInquiry(int BusinessLineCode, int ClientCaseId, string callingApp) { XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("VSI.EWSSearch.config")); logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (VsiEWSSearch)); I also put the root inside the log4net node and I took out the config sections node. How can I take out the configuration node? Everything is in it?

Comment: Logging is working when I run the service and the client locally. It's logging to the framework's logging file. The issue is when I run the client (which is a VB6) client from another machine (which happens to be a Virtual Machine) then logging doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I often forget the XmlConfigurator, which causes the logger to fail without errors or exceptions. You can call the configurator alternatively using this attribute in the class file that uses the logger: `[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`